# How to use multiple method in single route in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I want to use more than one method in a single route using laravel. I'm try this way but when i dd() it's show the plan string.

```
Route::get('/user',[
'uses' => 'AppController@user',
'as'   => 'useraccess',
'roles'=> 'HomeController@useroles', 
]);
```

When i dd()  **'roles'** option it's show the plan string like this.

```
"roles" => "HomeController@useroles"
```

my middleware check the role this way.

```
 $actions=$request->route()->getAction();
 $roles=isset($actions['roles'])? $actions['roles'] : null;
```

Comment: Why? Isn't this exactly what something like `middlewares` were made for?

Comment: It's made for pass User role to **middleware**

Comment: Why not just do it in the controller?

Comment: How can i do this.please let me know.

Comment: I suggest moving `useroles` into the `User` model, naming it `roles`, then call it from your controller with `$roles = (new User)->roles()`

Comment: How can i set it with my routes ??

Comment: You don't, rest routes map to a single controller method.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `roles`? Can you explain in a little more detail what flow you're hoping to get out of this?

Comment: I want check role in my middle-ware this way,** $actions=$request->route()->getAction();
        $roles=isset($actions['roles'])? $actions['roles'] : null;** for this way how can i do that.

Answer (score 22):

The simplest way to accept multiple HTTP methods in a single route is to use the `match` method, like so:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/user', [
    'uses' => 'AppController@user',
    'as'   => 'useraccess',
    'roles'=> 'HomeController@useroles', 
]);
```

As for your middleware, to check the HTTP request type, a tidier way would be:

`$method = request()->method();`

And if you need to check for a specific method:

```
if (request()->isMethod('post')) {
    // do stuff for post methods
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do multiple methods on a single route:

```
Route::get('/route', 'RouteController@index');
Route::post('/route', 'RouteController@create');
Route::put('/route', 'RouteController@update');
/* Would be easier to use
* Route::put('/route/{route}', 'RouteController@update');
* Since Laravel gives you the Model of the primary key you've passed
* in to the route.
*/
Route::delete('/route', 'RouteController@destroy');
```

If you've written your own middleware, you can wrap the routes in a `Route::group` and apply your middleware to those routes, or individual routes respectively.

```
Route::middleware(['myMiddleware'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/route', 'RouteController@index');
    Route::post('/route', 'RouteController@create');
    Route::put('/route', 'RouteController@update');
});
```

Or

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'myMiddleware'], function() {
    Route::get('/route', 'RouteController@index');
    Route::post('/route', 'RouteController@create');
    Route::put('/route', 'RouteController@update');
});
```

Whichever is easier for you to read.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-groups